# Adding jquery event listener to a login form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added a javascript event listener to a function called *validate* and it worked fine. Now I'm thinking if it is possible (I bet it is) to change it to jquery event listener? I'm not really sure should I use submit or click or whatever?

HTML:

```
<button id ="clickButton" class="sign-in">Sign In</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var login = document.getElementById("clickButton");
login.addEventListener('click', validate, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use click event listener. Here is how you can do this in jquery:

```
$(function(){
   $("#clickButton").click(function(){
      // Your code here.
   });
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A72Jk/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to register a click event handler, to select the element using id use the [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
$('#clickButton').click(validate)
```